# pagination a lists of category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My project need to list all categories in one page with pagination.

Example: I had 100 categories and need to show 10 categories for each page with number pagination below.

How can I do that in Wordpress?

```
$taxonomy = 'category';
    if( !isset($_GET['showall']) ):

        $total_terms = wp_count_terms( 'category' );
        $pages = ceil($total_terms/$per_page);
        // if there's more than one page
        if( $pages > 1 ):
            echo '<ul>';

            for ($pagecount = 1; $pagecount <= $pages; $pagecount++):
                echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link('news', $taxonomy).'page/'.$pagecount.'/">'.$pagecount.'</a></li>';
            endfor;

            echo '</ul>';
        endif;

    else:

    endif;
```

It return as domain/category/news/page/number but i click to page number it's return to homepage.

Comment: Can you please show us the code which you have tried? Please don't expect others to write full code for you. Hire a freelancer for that job. Here users volunteer to help other users when they are stuck on a specific programming related problem.

Comment: I updated my code so far.Ty

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it by my self...
Here is the code , so feel free to use if u want.

```
               <?php
                    $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
                    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
                    $category_per_page = 2;
                    $page = 1;
                    $offset = 0;

                    $taxonomy = 'category';
                    if (!empty($_GET['page'])){
                        $offset = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $category_per_page;
                    }

                    $tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'parent' => $cat_id,'number' => $category_per_page, 'offset' => $offset , 'hide_empty' => false ) );
                    $totalCategories = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'parent' => $cat_id, 'hide_empty' => false ) );
                    $totalNumber = sizeof($totalCategories);
                    $totalPagination = round($totalNumber / $category_per_page);

                    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) :
                        $args=array('cat' => $tax_term->term_id,'showposts'=>6);
                        $query=new WP_Query($args);
                ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h3 class="heading-title"><a href="<?=esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy));?>" title="<?=the_title();?>"><?= $tax_term->name;?></a></h3>
                    </div>
                    <section class="list-items owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag" id="projects-slide">
                        <?php while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();?>
                        <div class="item">
                            <figure class="item-featured-img">
                                <a href="<?=the_permalink();?>">
                                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                                        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail',array('class' => 'img-responsive center-block'));
                                    else : ?>
                                        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/no-img.jpg" alt="<?php echo $alt_text; ?>">
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                </a>
                                <figcaption class="title-item">
                                    <h2><a href="<?=the_permalink();?>" title="<?=the_title();?>"><?=the_title();?></a></h2>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="excerpt">
                                <p><?php echo cut_string(get_the_content(),65,'');?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endwhile;?>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach;?>

                <form method="GET">
                    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $totalPagination ; $i++) { ?>
                    <button name="page" value="<?= $i+1 ?>"><?= $i+1 ?></button>
                    <?php } ?>
                </form>
```